# Same regex behaving differently in Apache and Nginx

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I'm trying to covert [5G Blacklist](https://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/) to from Apache(.htaccess) to Nginx(.conf). There is a line in .htaccess that is causing problem:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>  
    RedirectMatch 403 (\,|\)\+|/\,/|\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\||\\\"\\\")  
</IfModule>
```

I have converted it to .conf as follows:

**Code included in http block**

```
map $request_uri $bad_uri {  
    default 0;  
    "~*(\,|\)\+|/\,/|\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\||\\\"\\\")" 1;  
}
```

**Code included in server block**

```
if ($bad_uri) {  
    return 403;  
}
```

As far as I know both Apache and Nginx use [perl regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) so no change should be required when converting from former to the latter. However, following URI is giving 403 on Nginx but working fine on Apache:

> <s>www.example.com/some,url,with,commas</s>
>   www.example.com/?q=some,url,with,commas

Comment: Could you explain in plain english, what this regexp should do?

Comment: @AlexeyTen 5G blacklist is supposed to block bad bots, scrapers, URL scans, etc. This is a line from that list. From my limited knowledge I can tell that this regex should match any URL having `,` `)+` `/, /` `{0}` `(/(` `...` `+++` `|` or `\"\"`

Comment: So, I can't understand. Should `some,url,with,commas` be blocked or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue.

In Apache **RedirectMatch**  matches only the url without query string whereas **$request_uri** in nginx maps to url with query string.

So the correct code for Nginx is:

```
map $uri $bad_uri {  
default 0;  
"~*(\,|\)\+|/\,/|\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\||\\\"\\\")" 1;  
}
```